# Reappear bubbles js and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I'm giving up and I'm here to see if you can give me some hints.

I made this bubble effect in which when I touch each bubble it pops, but I can't get the bubbles to reappear after a few seconds (as if they were new bubbles).

I leave the code here below:

```js
function changeStyle1() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop1");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle2() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop2");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle3() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop3");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle4() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop4");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle5() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop5");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle6() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop6");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle7() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop7");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle8() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop8");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle9() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop9");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle10() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop10");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}

function changeStyle11() {
  var element = document.getElementById("pop11");
  element.style.opacity = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #333;
  font: 100% Lato, Arial, Sans Serif;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


/* OBJECTS */

button {
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.bubble {
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

.bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.bubble::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 45px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.bubble span {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bubble span:nth-child(1) {
  inset: 10px;
  border-left: 15px solid #0fb4ff;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

.bubble span:nth-child(2) {
  inset: 10px;
  border-right: 15px solid #ff4484;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

.bubble span:nth-child(3) {
  inset: 20px;
  border-top: 15px solid #ffeb3b;
  filter: blur(8px);
}

.bubble span:nth-child(4) {
  inset: 30px;
  border-left: 15px solid #ff4484;
  filter: blur(12px);
}

.bubble span:nth-child(5) {
  inset: 10px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #fff;
  filter: blur(8px);
  transform: rotate (330deg);
}


/* ANIMATIONS */

.x1 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 25s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: -5%;
  top: 5%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.x2 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 5%;
  top: 80%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
  transform: scale(0.4);
}

.x3 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 28s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 10%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
  transform: scale(0.7);
}

.x4 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
  transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x5 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 30%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
}

.x6 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 21s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.x7 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 20s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 65%;
  top: 70%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.4);
  transform: scale(0.4);
}

.x8 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 22s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
  transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x9 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 29s linear infinite, sideWays 4s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 90%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.6);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.6);
  transform: scale(0.6);
}

.x10 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 26s linear infinite, sideWays 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 80%;
  top: 80%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.3);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.3);
  transform: scale(0.3);
}

.x11 {
  -webkit-animation: animateBubble 19s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: animateBubble 19s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  animation: animateBubble 19s linear infinite, sideWays 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  left: 90%;
  top: 90%;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
  transform: scale(0.7);
}


/* KEYFRAMES */

@-webkit-keyframes animateBubble {
  0% {
    margin-top: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes animateBubble {
  0% {
    margin-top: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
}

@keyframes animateBubble {
  0% {
    margin-top: 1000px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top: -100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes sideWays {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes sideWays {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes sideWays {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Pure CSS Animated Bubbles</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="changeStyle()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="background-wrap">
    <button id="pop1" onclick="changeStyle1()" class="bubble x1">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop2" onclick="changeStyle2()" class="bubble x2">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop3" onclick="changeStyle3()" class="bubble x3">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop4" onclick="changeStyle4()" class="bubble x4">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop5" onclick="changeStyle5()" class="bubble x5">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop6" onclick="changeStyle6()" class="bubble x6">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop7" onclick="changeStyle7()" class="bubble x7">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop8" onclick="changeStyle8()" class="bubble x8">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop9" onclick="changeStyle9()" class="bubble x9">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop10" onclick="changeStyle10()" class="bubble x10">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
    <button id="pop11" onclick="changeStyle11()" class="bubble x11">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </button>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/tomas-saint-romain/details/LYdaMRG

Comment: You may like to look into the amount of CPU/GPU the animations are using, it seems quite high (so a potential battery-flatterner). You could for example set a bubble to display: none rather than set opacity when it is burst so it doesn't have to be animated until you bring it back with display: block after a certain time. Also transforms using translation can cut down on processor time compared to top and left changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need all of those functions,just one will be enough

**JS**

```
    const changeStyleToBubble = (id) => {

      //we get the id directly from the html element,as parameter
      const element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.style.opacity = "0";
      
      //set it back to 1 after 2 seconds (2000 ms)
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.style.opacity = "1";
      }, 2000)

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<button id="pop2" onclick="changeStyleToBubble(this.id)" class="bubble x2">
```